# Using grepl in R

Tags: r, grepl

In which cases could these 2 different ways of implimentation would give different results?

```
data(mtcars)
firstWay <- mtcars[grepl('6',mtcars$cyl),]
SecondWay <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl=='6',]
```

If these ways always give the same results which of them is recommended and why? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the package microbenchmark, we can see which is faster

```
library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(mtcars[grepl('6',mtcars$cyl),], mtcars[mtcars$cyl=='6',], times=10000)

    Unit: microseconds
                         expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 mtcars[grepl("6", mtcars$cyl), ] 229.080 234.738 247.5324 236.693 239.417 6713.914 10000
      mtcars[mtcars$cyl == "6", ] 214.902 220.210 231.0240 221.956 224.471 7759.507 10000
```

It looks like `==` is faster, so when possible you should use that

However, the functions do not do exactly the same thing. `grepl` searches for if the string is present at all wheras `==` checks whether the expressions are equal

```
grepl("6", mtcars$disp)

 [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

mtcars$disp == "6"

[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[18] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

`mtcars$cyl` is a numeric column, so you would be better off comparing it to a number using mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 6, ].

But the difference between the equality operator `==` and `grepl` is that `==` will only be `TRUE` for members of the vector which are equal to `"6"`, while `grepl` will match any member of the vector which has a 6 anywhere within it.

So, for example:

```
String                                                   ==     grepl
6                                                        TRUE   TRUE
123456                                                   FALSE  TRUE
6ABC                                                     FALSE  TRUE
This is a long sentence which happens to have a 6 in it  FALSE  TRUE
Whereas this long sentence does not                      FALSE  FALSE
```

The equivalent `grepl` pattern would be "^6$". There's a tutorial (one of many) on regex at http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think that the fist difference is that with `grepl` you can subset even if you do not already know, for example `6`, but you can try to search a rows that start or end with `6`.

If you try to do this with normal subsetting technique you'll have an empty object because, for example `^6`, is not recognized as a regular expression but as a string with the symbol `^` and `6`.

I am sure there are other differences but I am sure professional users will provide more detailed answers.

For the side os which one could be preferred maybe there can be reasons of efficiency:

```
system.time(mtcars[grepl('^6',mtcars$cyl),])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.029   0.002   0.035 
system.time(mtcars[mtcars$cyl=='6',])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.031   0.002   0.046
```

This little example can be just a guide and as @Nick K suggested first further (and precise) investigations have to be done with `microbenchmark` . Of course with big dataset I barely believe that a professional users (or one in need of speed) will prefer both of them but maybe it will rely on data table, or tools like `dplyr` written in lower level language and so more fast.

Comment: `system.time` isn't really much use for really quick expressions like this. `microbenchmark` as per @CactusWoman's answer is much better.